# Pandas - combine two unstacked data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a data set where I unstack the data, and get the first and last rows.

```
>>> print df.iloc[[(0), (-1)]]

     Distance               
Node            0     1     2   
Time                            
0             27.0  54.0  97.0  
60            22.0  49.0  92.0
```

then I use `df1 = (df.loc[0] - df.iloc[(-1)]).unstack()` to get the difference of the two rows

```
Node            0    1    2    
Distance       5.0  5.0  5.0
```

And finally, I want to concatenate/combine the two data sets (`df` and `df1`).

```
 >>> print pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)

               (Distance, 0)  (Distance, 1)  (Distance, 2) 
0                   27.0           54.0           NaN  
60                  22.0           49.0           92.0 
Distance            NaN             NaN            NaN
```

but I'm getting `NaN`.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I want my output to look like this

```
     Distance               
Node            0     1     2   
Time                            
0             27.0  54.0  97.0  
60            22.0  49.0  92.0 
Difference     5.0  5.0   5.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the use of `unstack` is not needed for what you are trying to achieve. Below are a couple of alternatives. To simplify the formatting I've omitted index and column names.

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [27.0, 22.0], 1: [54.0, 49.0], 2: [97.0, 92.0]},
                  index=[0, 60])

print(df)

       0     1     2
0   27.0  54.0  97.0
60  22.0  49.0  92.0
```

#### pd.DataFrame.loc

Add a new row by index via `pd.DataFrame.loc` with a row label.

```
df.loc['Distance'] = df.loc[0] - df.iloc[-1]
```

#### pd.Series.to_frame + concat

Convert your difference series to a dataframe, then transpose and concatenate.

```
diff = (df.loc[0] - df.iloc[-1]).to_frame().T
diff.index = ['Distance']

res = pd.concat([df, diff])
```

**Result**

The result for both methods:

```
print(res)

             0     1     2
0         27.0  54.0  97.0
60        22.0  49.0  92.0
Distance   5.0   5.0   5.0
```